# How to resolve swept AABB collision when two boxes are hit at exactly the same time?

Tags: collision-detection, collision-resolution, aabb

I've read many posts here about sweeping AABB collisions and the corner problem. But I still couldn't solve the problem.

In the image below, the object starts touching both boxes, and when I apply a diagonal motion, it collides with both, and getting the collision times I get 0.0 for both.

Many of the posts that I read recommend sorting collisions by the time of impact, but what do I do if the times are equal?

In this example I'm using tiles, but I want a solution that will work with AABBs of different sizes.

[image]

Here are the links to the important sections of the code

Raycast: https://github.com/anynoise00/bevy_simple_aabb/blob/v0.2.0/src/collision/raycast.rs
(above the intersection function there's a link to the article that I read to make the RayVsBox intersection test)

Aabb: https://github.com/anynoise00/bevy_simple_aabb/blob/v0.2.0/src/collision/aabb.rs

Broad, narrow and solve phases: https://github.com/anynoise00/bevy_simple_aabb/blob/v0.2.0/src/collision/mod.rs
(the sorting happens at the narrowphase, I tried also sorting it by the far times when the near times where equal, but it is still sticking to the corner of walls when moving vertically)

Maybe there is something wrong with the code?

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A collision detection algorithm will necessarily compute one collision before another, even if the estimated time for them is the same. So, a good criterion for ordering collisions before solving them could be: **lower time first; if time is the same, early detected first**.

This can be easily achieved using a [priority queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue), where the priority value is the collision time and ordering entries with the same priority has FIFO criteria (First In, First Out, then latest enqueued values go at the bottom of their priority level).

Here's a pseudocode example, where `pairX` is a valid collision detected during the narrow phase and waiting for the collision response, and the float is the collision time estimated for that pair:

```
collisions = PriorityQueue()

collisions.Enqueue(pair0, 0.1)
collisions.Enqueue(pair1, 0.0)
collisions.Enqueue(pair2, 0.05)
collisions.Enqueue(pair3, 0.04)
collisions.Enqueue(pair4, 0.5)
collisions.Enqueue(pair5, 0.1)
collisions.Enqueue(pair6, 0.01)

print(collisions)
```

The result will be:

```
[pair1, pair6, pair3, pair2, pair0, pair5, pair4]
```

Comment: A challenge here is that solving the collision with B before C will nudge the object sideways (the separating displacement is smallest horizontally). This leads to the classic tile collision problem where a character who was attempting to move left gets stuck as though they've hit a solid wall. What we want here is either that C gets solved first, even if B was earlier in detection order, or we observe the two collisions together and notice that an upward displacement resolves both simultaneously.

Comment: the tile problem is exactly what I'm dealing with, and I forgot to mention it in the post. I'm thinking in changing my entire lib to using int values. Maybe with this there'll never be a collision with the same time as the other on the when the object is exactly as is in the image.

Comment: Later I will try to do as you said and try to analyze the displacement, and check if it resolve both equally

Comment: It didn't work as I expected, but when I implemented it I discovered the error was really in my code. Thanks for the help!